# Separable metric space spanned by base

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a metric space . If $X$ happens to be separable ,then countably many open subsets are enough to form a base. 
How to prove this one?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: True. How to delete it or close it

Comment: I think you can find the option under the body of the question